# Running Out Of My Timers

Tags: c, unix, timer

if (TIMER_1_EVENT)
       sendPeriodicMessage_1_ToProcess_1

```
if (TIMER_2_EVENT)
   sendPeriodicMessage_2_ToProcess_2

if (TIMER_3_EVENT)
   sendPeriodicMessage_3_ToProcess_3

if (TIMER_4_EVENT)
    sendPeriodicMessage_4_ToProcess_4

if (TIMER_5_EVENT)
    sendPeriodicMessage_5_ToProcess_5
```

I am working on the code for this process that basically sends, receives, forwards different kind of messages to other processes. Now i have 4 timers that i use to send different periodic messages. Now there is a fifth type of message that needs to be sent. But Maximum number of timers allowed in this project is 4(that i have no control over, can't change that macro value to 5). Also, none of these five messages share same time interval. What do i do? what approach do you suggest i can use here to get this done?

```
sendPeriodicMessage_X_ToProcess_Y     // X & Y be message and process number
{
   Init_Timer();
   ...
   ...
}

void InitTimer()
{
   if (num_Timers >= MaxTimers)    // MaxTimers is 4
       //don't init timer
   else
       // init timer 
}
```

Comment: Well, this is quite mysterious.  Otherwise the only thing that occurs to me is that you could send a message on a timer with twice the frequency, half the time, to the 5th.  That is have a flag that toggles on/off each event and only send the periodic message when it's on.  Indeed using this method you could send messages to all of your processes using only one timer.

Comment: what is the periodicity of each message ?

Comment: You have just one timer yourself, the watch on your wrist.  Yet it is good enough to help you show up on time for an arbitrary number of appointments throughout the day.  Just do it the exact same way in your code.  Use one timer and a sorted list of due times.  Start the timer with an interval for the first due time.  When it ticks you remove all of the ones with the same due time from the list.  Stop and restart the timer when you add a new due time.

Comment: Please pick one of C and C++. Is this a C or a C++ question?